# php MySql Joining Tables with Table.A name matching Table.B Column name

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried everything I can think of. Issue. Main Table has column that matches second table name. I cannot join. Any help?

```
SELECT 
    Inspections.Id,
    Inspections.Custom_Specs,
    Custom_Specs.Id AS Custom_Id                
FROM Inspections
    JOIN Custom_Specs ON Inspections.Custom_Specs=Custom_Specs.Id

Inspections.Id,           (Value: 1)
Inspections.Custom_Specs, (Value: 5)
Custom_Specs.Id,          (Value: 5)
Custom_Specs.Spec_Name ,   (Value: Name Of Spec)
Custom_Specs.Id AS Specs_Id
```

Output:

```
<option value=\"". $row["Specs_Id."] ."\">". $row["Spec_Name"] ."</option>
```

UPDATED:

Query which is working for me:

```
SELECT 
   Inspections.Id, 
   Inspections.Custom_Specs, 
   Custom_Specs.Id, 
   Custom_Specs.Spec_Name
FROM Inspections 
LEFT JOIN Custom_Specs ON Inspections.Custom_Specs = Custom_Specs.Id
```

Comment: Any errors? Any message? What exactly was supposed to happen?

Comment: Sorry. Once complete I echo " ".$row["Spec_Name"]." "; 2nd Column from Custom_Specs Table, but it php page shows blank. Aka the form disappears.

Comment: Sounds a little like an XY-problem. Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: Use the describe tablename and give us the output of Inspections and Custom_specs, also the expected results.

Comment: ok, Trying to post but its pending peer review. Inspections is the main table. The column Custom_Specs holds the Id from Custom_Specs table. I need the Spec_Name column from the Custom_Specs row tied to Inspections.Custom_Specs column to display. So, expected result would output the Spec_Name

Answer (score 0):

Your comparing specs to id column. These are two different data types. The query below should do the work for you :

```
SELECT 
   Custom_Specs.Id
   Custom_Specs.Spec_Name
FROM Inspections
LEFT JOIN Custom_Specs ON Inspections.Custom_Specs = Custom_Specs.Id
```

Comment: That brought back the form input, but not displaying the row value. This happens every time I LEFT JOIN. It doesnt output the Custom_Specs.Spec_Name row. I Just re-read your suggestion. Inspections.Id is not the same as Custom_Specs.Id. Custom_Specs.Id is held in the Inspections table in Column Custom_Specs as an int. Custom_Specs Table holds that value in .Id

Comment: It is confusing. Please provide your database tables with some examples and the expected output.

Comment: EDIT For N00b
Inspections.Id,           (Value: 1)
Inspections.Custom_Specs, (Value: 5)
Custom_Specs.Id,          (Value: 5)
Custom_Specs.Spec_Name ,   (Value: Name Of Spec)
Custom_Specs.Id AS Specs_Id

Output:

<option value=\"". $row["Specs_Id."] ."\">". $row["Spec_Name"] ."</option>